# Angular 2: Convert Observable to Promise

Tags: typescript, angular, promise, observable

**Q) How do I convert the following observable to a promise so I can call it with `.then(...)`?**

My method I want to convert to a promise:

```
  this._APIService.getAssetTypes().subscribe(
    assettypes => {
        this._LocalStorageService.setAssetTypes(assettypes);
    },
    err => {
        this._LogService.error(JSON.stringify(err))
    },
    () => {}
  );
```

The service method it calls:

```
  getAssetTypes() {
    var method = "assettype";
    var url = this.apiBaseUrl + method;

    return this._http.get(url, {})
      .map(res => <AssetType[]>res.json())
      .map((assettypes) => {
        assettypes.forEach((assettypes) => {
          // do anything here you might need....
      });
      return assettypes;
    });      
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The Most answers below have [`toPromise()`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html) operator, that has been deprecated in RxJS 5.5+

Answer (score 142, accepted):

**rxjs7**

```js
lastValueFrom(of('foo'));
```

https://indepth.dev/posts/1287/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated

**rxjs6**

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/2868#issuecomment-360633707

> Don't pipe. It's on the Observable object by default.
>
> ```
> Observable.of('foo').toPromise(); // this
> ```

**rxjs5**

```js
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

...

this._APIService.getAssetTypes()
.map(assettypes => {
  this._LocalStorageService.setAssetTypes(assettypes);
})
.toPromise()
.catch(err => {
  this._LogService.error(JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Comment: Get this error:

[ts] Argument of type '(assettypes: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PromiseConstructor'. Property 'all' is missing in type '(assettypes: any) => void'.
(parameter) assettypes: any

Comment: What does `getAssetTypes()` return?

Comment: an array of interface type AssetType

Comment: It needs to return an `Observable` for this to work. The code in your question also only works if it returns an `Observable` (to call `subscribe(...)` on it)

Comment: I've updated my question with the service method that is called. thanks.

Comment: Ok, it returns an `Observable`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109848/discussion-between-dave-and-gunter-zochbauer).

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer has `import 'rxjs/operator/add/toPromise';` been changed to: `import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';` ?

Comment: toPromise is deprecated. How would we do this now?

Comment: It's not. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 23):

observable can be converted to promise like this:

```
import { firstValueFrom, lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
...
lastValueFrom(observable).then(lastValue=>...);
firstValueFrom(observable).then(firstValue=>...);
```

`toPromise()` was the previous solution, deprecated from RxJS 7, it was:

```
let promise=observable.toPromise();
```

Comment: If I conver this to promise I can also catch an error right?

Comment: you can surround with try catch and even user promise.catch()

Comment: `toPromise` is now deprecated.

Answer (score 14):

The proper way to make Observable a Promise, in your case would be following

```js
getAssetTypesPromise() Observable<any> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.getAssetTypes().subscribe((response: any) => {
        resolve(response);
      }, reject);
    });
}
```

Comment: This can be further simplified to `return new Promise((resolve, reject) => this.getAssetTypes().subscribe(resolve, reject));`

Answer (score 13):

you dont really need to do this just do ...

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';


this.esQueryService.getDocuments$.first().subscribe(() => {
        event.enableButtonsCallback();
      },
      (err: any) => console.error(err)
    );
    this.getDocuments(query, false);
```

first() ensures the subscribe block is only called once (after which it will be as if you never subscribed), exactly the same as a promises then()

Comment: Correct, the promise is only resolved at the time the observables completes, using .first() or .take(1) will ensure it's the case after the first emit.

Comment: The problem here is we cannot use `async/await` pattern.

Comment: first().toPromise() will give you promise and then you can use async/await

Answer (score 11):

**Edit:**

`.toPromise()` is now deprecated in RxJS 7 (source: https://rxjs.dev/deprecations/to-promise)

**New answer:**

> As a replacement to the deprecated toPromise() method, you should use
> one of the two built in static conversion functions firstValueFrom or
> lastValueFrom.

Example:

```
import { interval, lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs';
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
 
async function execute() {
  const source$ = interval(2000).pipe(take(10));
  const finalNumber = await lastValueFrom(source$);
  console.log(`The final number is ${finalNumber}`);
}
 
execute();
 
// Expected output:
// "The final number is 9"
```

---

**Old answer:**

A lot of comments are claiming `toPromise` deprecated but as you can see [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.2.2/src/internal/Observable.ts#L329-L343) it's not.

So please juste use `toPromise` (RxJs 6) as said:

```
//return basic observable
const sample = val => Rx.Observable.of(val).delay(5000);
//convert basic observable to promise
const example = sample('First Example')
  .toPromise()
  //output: 'First Example'
  .then(result => {
    console.log('From Promise:', result);
  });
```

async/await example:

```
//return basic observable
const sample = val => Rx.Observable.of(val).delay(5000);
//convert basic observable to promise
const example = await sample('First Example').toPromise()
// output: 'First Example'
console.log('From Promise:', result);
```

Read more [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html).

---

Note: Otherwise you can use `.pipe(take(1)).toPromise` but as said you shouldn't have any problem using above example.

Comment: it is deprecated and might be removed in v8. your link is for v6.

Answer (score 5):

**toPromise is [deprecated](https://indepth.dev/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated/) in RxJS 7.**

**Use:**

1. `lastValueFrom`

Used when we are interested in the stream of values. Works like the former `toPromise`

Example

```
public async getAssetTypes() {
  const assetTypes$ = this._APIService.getAssetTypes()
  this.assetTypes = await lastValueFrom(assetTypes$);
}
```

2. `firstValueFrom`

Used when we are not interested in the stream of values but just the first value and then unsubscribe from the stream

```
public async getAssetTypes() {
  const assetTypes$ = this._APIService.getAssetTypes()
  this.assetTypes = await firstValueFrom(assetTypes$); // get first value and unsubscribe
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Observable to promise just by single line of code as below:

```
let promisevar = observable.toPromise()
```

Now you can use then on the promisevar to apply then condition based on your requirement.

```
promisevar.then('Your condition/Logic');
```

Answer (score 0):

I like it raw so this one since **toPromise()** is no more

```
   const status = await new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
     someObs$.subscribe({
      next: resolve,
      error: reject,
    });
  });
```

A sophisticated way is using https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom

```
  const replyTo = new AsyncSubject();

  replyTo.next(false);
  replyTo.next(false);
  replyTo.next(true);

  replyTo.complete();

  const status = await lastValueFrom(replyTo) // true
```

Answer (score 0):

As most mentioned, you can simply use `myObservable.toPromise()`. However, it's going to be removed in the next version of rxJs. For those who want to keep using `toPromise()` however (perhaps to avoid changing it throughout multiple projects they own), you can create an 'extension method' of sorts, to have 'your own' `toPromise()` that won't be deprecated. You can use this now even before it gets removed from rxJs.

```
declare module "rxjs" {
    interface Observable<T> {
        /**
         * Extension method. Applies 'lastValueFrom' to Observable<T>.
         */
        toPromise(): Promise<T | undefined>;
    }
}

Observable.prototype.toPromise = function <T>(this: Observable<T>): Promise<T> {
    return lastValueFrom(this);
};
```

To get this to show up everywhere, you must put this in the file that bootstraps your application. For Angular apps, that can be `main.js`.