# Call Promise inside Observable

Tags: angular, rxjs, es6-promise

I have to make an API call (returns `Promise`) after another API call (returns `Observable`).

The `userService.getAuthUser()` returns an `Observable`.

The `userService.updateUser()` returns a `Promise`.

I can achieve that by putting `updateUser()` inside `getAuthUser()`

```
this.userService.getAuthUser().subscribe((res) =>{
  this.userService.updateUser(res.id, <User>({
    name: 'Sample Name'
  })).then((res) =>{
    console.log('update user success');
  }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('update user failed');
  })
},
(err) => {
  console.log('get auth user failed');
})
```

But i feel that is not very good doing this way, kind of callback hell, any better way to do so?

Note: I can't change `userService.updateUser()`  to `Observable`.

Comment: You are dependent on the value returned by the observable for the next `updateUser()` part. So this is fine. If you want to have a cleaner code, create another method to update the user with an argument and call it inside the subscribe

Comment: You can convert an Observable to a Promise and chain Promises though. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777284/angular-2-convert-observable-to-promise https://stackoverflow.com/a/54710279/495157

Comment: You can also convert a Promise to an Observable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39319279/convert-promise-to-observable/39319314 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771855/chaining-observables-in-rxjs

Answer (score 9):

There are a few ways you can achieve this.

**One way** if you want the getAuthUser stream to remain active is to transform the promise to an observable with the [from operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html#example-2-observable-from-promise). This will allow you to continue the stream and react to errors/handle success for the entire stream. You can also specify where in the stream to react to specific errors with the [catchError operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/error_handling/catch.html).

Something similar to:

```
this.userService.getAuthUser()
  .pipe(
    catchError(err => {
      // throw an error how you like, see the 'throw' operator
      // can also create with other operators like 'of'
    }),
    switchMap(auth =>
      from( // will detect promise and return observable
        this.userService.updateUser(res.id, <User>({
          name: 'Sample Name'
        }))
      )
    ),
    catchError(err => {
      // throw an error how you like, see the 'throw' operator
      // can also create with other operators like 'of'
    })

  ).subscribe(
    (res) => {
      // if you were expecting data at this point
    }, (err) => {
      // if you threw the error
    }
  )
```

**Another way** if you don't need the stream to remain active, you can convert the Observable from the first stream to a Promise with `.toPromise()`. From here, you have two typical paths to follow. You can use [async/await](https://javascript.info/async-await), or just chain the promises.

For the async await, something similar to:

```
// the method will have to be async for await to not show errors

const authUser = await this.userService.getAuthUser().toPromise();

// determine if you should update
// if so

const updateUserResult = await this.userService.updateUser(res.id, <User>({name: 'Sample Name'}));
```

Comment: for the `catchError` part it shows some error `Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<void>) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.`, i have to use `throw`

Comment: Which catchError part (or both)? Sorry, it was a rough up to give the "stream" example. I'd be happy to update with what you've found

Comment: both actually, i have throw the error like `catchError(err => {
        console.log(err)
        throw err;
    }` else IDE is complaning

Comment: Oh, gotcha, the "return an observable still" part. throw is one option, but any way you can create a new observable is valid. One use case is to catch the error, handle it there, and change the stream to a new observable so downstream effects can react differently if needed.

Answer (score 3):

```js
import { flatMap, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of, from } from 'rxjs';

this.userService
  .getAuthUser()
  .pipe(
    flatMap(
      ({ id }) =>
        from(this.userService.updateUser(id)).pipe(
          map(response => {
            console.log('update user success');
            return response;
          }),
          catchError(error => {
            console.log('update user failed');
            return of(error);
          })
        ),
      catchError(error => {
        console.log('get auth user failed');
        return of(error);
      })
    )
  )
  .subscribe();
```