# How to get the data from an Observable and put it in array Angular

Tags: angular

What is the best way to access the data of an observable.

```
data: DataModel[]; //this is the observable where the data is stored
dataID = null;

constructor(private someService: SomeService){}

ngOnInit() {

  this.dataID = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.someService.query(this.dataID).subscribe(res => this.data = res) //here I get all the data from the observable                     

}
```

If I need the data stored inside to use it, how could I put it in an array?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777284/angular-2-convert-observable-to-promise

Answer (score 1):

First define data variable as Observable only if you want to show it dynamically in the front end.!

```
data: Observable;
dataID = null;

constructor(private someService: SomeService){}

ngOnInit() {

  this.dataID = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
  this.someService.query(this.dataID).subscribe(res => this.data = res) //here I get all the data from the observable                     

}
```

In the HTML file you can simply use:

```
{{data.name|async}} // name or any other field defined in database
```

this will display the value in the HTML. Now if you want to store the value in an array you can follow this approach:

```
dataArray: any[] = []
dataID = null;

constructor(private someService: SomeService){}

ngOnInit() {

      this.dataID = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
      this.someService.query(this.dataID).subscribe(res =>
      this.dataArray.push(res))             
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now i can put it in the observable in the array but, How can I get only one data from the array? I need it to send it to another function

Answer (score 0):

You can define data as an observable

```
data: Observable<T>
```

Then in the subscriber ,

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.data = this.someService.query(this.dataID);
}
```

In HTML , you can use the async pipe to subscribe to use the array

```
<div *ngIf="(data | async) as myArray">
  <div *ngFor="let item of array">
  {{item.name}}
  <div>
</div>
```