# Why the conversion from this Observable to a Promise is not working in my Angular application?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-promise, angular-observable

I am pretty new in Angular and RxJS and in my code I have the following problem.

Into the **ngOnInit()** method I have this code snippet:

```
this.usersService.getAllUsers().toPromise().then(people => {
    this.people = people;
    this.peopleStr = people.map(person => person.complete_name);
    this.loading = false;
});
```

That is calling the **getAllUsers()** method on the **UserService** class:

```
getAllUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
    this.usersList = this.db.collection('Users').snapshotChanges();
    return this.usersList;
}
```

As you can see this **getAllUsers()** method return an **Observable** so to use the **then()** function I converted the result of the call to this **getAllUsers()** into a **Promise** using the **toPromise()**.

But it seems it is not working because, using the debugger, I see that it never execute the code inside the **then()** function

Why? What is wrong? What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Comment: [please see if this help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36777294/12163165)

Comment: If you're new to RxJS, I understand it's easy to convert observables to promises using `toPromise()` and take the easy route out. But `toPromise()` is [being deprecated](https://indepth.dev/rxjs-heads-up-topromise-is-being-deprecated/) in RxJS 7 (next major release) and out in RxJS 8. You're better off learning the observables and _subscribing_ to use it's notifications. Also observables provide much more functionality to control and adjust the flow of data using various [operators](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/operators).

Answer (score 3):

The `Promise` returned from `toPromise` will not resolve until the underlying observable completes.

So you have two choices

Remove `toPromise` altogether and use `subscribe`. This will trigger on every emission.

```
this.usersService.getAllUsers().subscribe(people => {
    this.people = people;
    this.peopleStr = people.map(person => person.complete_name);
    this.loading = false;
});
```

Or use `first()` to take the first value emitted and complete after the first emission.

```
this.usersService.getAllUsers().pipe(first()).toPromise().then(people => {
    this.people = people;
    this.peopleStr = people.map(person => person.complete_name);
    this.loading = false;
});
```

But as `toPromise`is being deprecated, so if you want only the first emission you better make it as follows:

```
this.usersService.getAllUsers().pipe(first()).subscribe(people => {
    this.people = people;
    this.peopleStr = people.map(person => person.complete_name);
    this.loading = false;
});
```

The last snippet is the same as the `toPromise` one.

So it depends on if you are interested in all emissions or only the first one.