# Wait to resolve Nested loops in a Typescript Subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, promise, observable

***Objective: I want to wait for all the nested loops to process before I can return final value.***

***Issue: Final value is returned before all the loops are processed.***

In the below code I am sending `paramListToComplete` to a data service to create a record and get that new record in the same call, so that I can set missing values in `paramListToComplete` and return `paramListToComplete` with updated values from service. The problem is the function returns the list before processing all the loops, so my `paramListToComplete` remains incomplete.

Does anybody know how to wait for all the loops to process or maybe convert all these nested loops to a promise and wait for all of them to resolve? Any help is appreciated.

```
  CompleteParamList(paramListToComplete): any {
    this.dataService.UpdateCall(paramListToComplete)
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          if (data) {
            for (var server of paramListToComplete) {
              for (var updatedData of data) {
                if (paramListToComplete.length === 1 && !server.Name) {
                  server.Name = updatedData.Name;
                }
                if (!server.serverCode && server.Name === updatedData.Name) {
                  server.serverCode = updatedData.serverCode;
                  for (var serverGroup of server.serverGroups) {
                    serverGroup.serverCode = updatedData.serverCode;
                  }
                  for (var updatedserverGroup of server.UpdatedserverGroups) {
                    updatedserverGroup.serverCode = updatedData.serverCode;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
    );
    return paramListToComplete;
  }

    UpdateCall(bdy: Array<testParams>) {
    let url = 'endpoint/path';
    let body = bdy;
    let options;
    return this.service.getToken()
      .map(Response =>
        options = new RequestOptions({
          headers: this.httpHelperService.buildHttpHeader(Response.json())
        }))
      .mergeMap(() => this.http.put(url, body, options)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch((this.handleError)));
  }
```

Comment: Does `this.dataService.UpdateCall(paramListToComplete).subscribe(...)` return a promise? If so, you just need to use the `await` keyword before calling it, then make `CompleteParamList` async: `async function CompleteParamList(...): Promise<any> {...}`

Comment: @smac89 I have added code for UpdateCall in the question, it returns a observable. I haven't had lot of experience with observables. So  struggling to handle this scenario.

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777284/angular-2-convert-observable-to-promise I believe your `.subscribe` method returns an observable which can be converted into a promise and then you can await it...

Comment: @smac89 a little correction, subscribe will return subscription instead of an observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be lazy! don't subscribe to observable returned from `UpdateCall` method in `CompleteParamList` method, instead return it and let the caller subscribe to it.
You can tap into the stream and modify the input param `paramListToComplete` and assuming you're on rxjs versoin 5 or below(for newer versions you can pipe it), the code will look like this:

```js
completeParamList(paramListToComplete): Observable<void> {
  return this.updateCall(paramListToComplete).tap(data => {
    // update paramListToComplete here...
  });
}
```

so now wherever you're using `completeParamList`, you can simply subscribe to it or convert it to promise(which I do not recommend as toPromise is deprecated in newer version of rxjs)

```js
someMethod() {
  const paramList = [];
  this.service.completeParamList(paramList).subscribe(_ => {
    // paramList has been updated, do your thang here...
  });
}
// alternative way
async someOtherMethod() {
  const paramList = [];
  await this.service.completeParamList(paramList).toPromise();
  // do your thang...
}
```