# How to await subscribe in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a function that suppose to return the user's info from an API

```
    getUser(){
      const token = localStorage.getItem("user");
      const tokenJson = JSON.parse(token as string);
      const email = tokenJson.user.email;
      const uid = tokenJson.user.uid;

      this.http.get(this.url + uid).subscribe((res: any) => {
        const user = {
          userId: uid,
          email: email,
          fName: res.fName,
          lName: res.lName,
        }
        return user;
      })   
    }
```

But the problem is that, when I call the function, I get undefined

```
   console.log(this.auth.getUser());
```

I tried to solve the problem by assigning the value to a variable, and then I accessed the variable directly  (Same issue)

```
   this.auth.getUser();
   console.log(this.auth.userInfo);
```

But finally, when I settimeout it works

```
   this.auth.getUser();
   setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.auth.userInfo);
   }, 1000);
```

now I'm sure it's an asynchronous issue
How can I wait for the result?
and what's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2: Convert Observable to Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36777284/angular-2-convert-observable-to-promise)

Comment: Your function return void -see that you have no return in your function. So you need rethink your code. Remember: "Your services should return observables, you subscribe in your component.".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to change the way you consume `getUser` method.

Think of it like this, fetching user from an API is an asynchronous action in nature and as your `getUser` method is performing that action, you need to wait for it to complete, now how do you do that?

```js
getUser() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("user");
    const tokenJson = JSON.parse(token as string);
    const email = tokenJson.user.email;
    const uid = tokenJson.user.uid;

    return this.http.get(this.url + uid).pipe(
        map(res => ({
            userId: uid,
            email: email,
            fName: res.fName,
            lName: res.lName,
        }))
    );
}
```

Now instead of subscribing to the observable inside `getUser`, you're returing an Observable to which you can subscribe to and do something after you get the response back like this:

```js
this.auth.getUser().subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

or like this:

```js
// this is new syntax that rxjs recommends
this.auth.getUser().subscribe({ next: res => console.log(res) });
```